# Is there a way to translate specific files in Weblate?

Tags: weblate

Weblate usually works by you picking a language to translate, then it will provide you with strings to translate into that language. However, at the moment I am primarily interested in translating one specific file, since it's a file that I wrote myself and therefore I am likely one of the best people to translate it. Is there a way to pick a specific file to translate and then have Weblate only pull strings out of that particular file?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are already using Git (or other [supported VCS](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/vcs.html)), just define proper file mask on [component creation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/projects.html#adding-translation-projects-and-components).

You can also start by [uploading files](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/vcs.html#local-files) if you don't have a repository yet.